# How to express $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i^m$ in terms of $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, summation

Is there any way to express $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i^m$ by polynomial of $X=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i$ and $Y=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i^2$? For example, if $n=2$ and $m=3$, it can be expressed as $\dfrac{X}{2}(X^2+Y)$. I think this problem is similar to those related to Newton's Sum, but it's actually slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlikely that you have enough elements. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials

Let's see; The homogeneous polynomials of degree $m$ that you can sum are 
$$ X^m, \; X^{m-2} Y, \;  X^{m-4} Y^2, \ldots   $$ giving a vector space of dimension $$ \left\lfloor \frac{m+1}{2} \right\rfloor.  $$

Next, considering the case that $m \leq n+1,$ the dimension of homogeneous symmetric polynomials   is $p(m),$ the partition function. This is because we can put the partition in decreasing order and assigning those as the exponents of your $a_0,a_1,\ldots$ he point of this is that we have a [good approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Approximation_formulas) 
$$ p(m) \approx \frac{1}{4 m \sqrt 3} \; \exp \left( \pi \; \sqrt {\frac{2m}{3}} \; \right).  $$
That is, the dimension of the space of homogeneous symmetric polynomials is much larger than the space of your expressions.

In conclusion, I do not expect your idea is a good bet.  If you can show me explicit formulae for larger $n,m$ pairs that is another story; there could be some special property of your sum with exponents exactly $m$ that makes this possible in general.

Comment: Thanks for nice information. I'm so glad that I could learn that I have to study symmetric polynomial to deep my knowledge about this sort of questions.